# How to omit controller name for Home views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Let's say I have this structure:

```
Home/
    Index
    About

Project/
    Index
    Details
```

How can I omit the controller name for Home views?

I want to write `{root}/About` instead of `{root}/Home/About`.
I also want `{root}/Project/Details/2` to work.

Here is what I tried in `RegisterRoutes`:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "DefaultRoute",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new
    {
        controller = "Home",
        action = "Index",
        id = UrlParameter.Optional
    }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "HomeRoute",
    url: "{action}",
    defaults: new
    {
        controller = "Home",
        action = "Index"
    }
);
```

**Edit:** I also tried swapping the order of my `MapRoute` calls but it still doesn't work.
What I need is:

```
{root}/Home/Index         > HomeController.Index
{root}/Home               > HomeController.Index
{root}                    > HomeController.Index
{root}/Home/About         > HomeController.About
{root}/About              > HomeController.About
{root}/Project/Index      > ProjectController.Index
{root}/Project            > ProjectController.Index
{root}/Project/Details/12 > ProjectController.Details
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just change the order of your `MapRoute` calls:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "HomeRoute",
    url: "{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

The 'Default' route has to be defined last, otherwise it matches all Url patterns and no further routes are evaluated.

**Update:**

As per your edit, since you want to preserve the 'controller-name-only' route as well. Try this:

```
public class ActionExistsConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    private readonly Type _controllerType;

    public ActionExistsConstraint(Type controllerType)
    {
        this._controllerType = controllerType;
    }

    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        var actionName = values["action"] as string;

        if (actionName == null || _controllerType == null || _controllerType.GetMethod(actionName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase) == null)
            return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "HomeRoute",
    url: "{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" },
    constraints: new { exists = new ActionExistsConstraint(typeof(HomeController)) }
);
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.ASPX#how_urls_are_matched_to_routes)

Comment: When I do this, HomeRoute still doesn't work ("The resource cannot be found" for `{root}/About`) and the default route doesn't work unless I specify the action name (even for index).

Comment: Thanks for the update but it doesn't match any views of the HomeController except Index. (`{root}/About` and `{root}/Home/About` both say "The resource cannot be found". Other controllers work without a problem, though)

Comment: Strange, because it does work for me. Do you have a Route Debugger installed? Your app resides in virtual directory? Other `Area` routes conflicting with yours?

Comment: Your edited sample works, I'm sorry. It turned out I had mistake in ordering again. Thank you so much.