# MVC Routing defaults

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

How to set up a rule in the routing configuration of MVC to send all requests of type domain.com/something to the Home Controller, the 'something' method, but the domain.com/something2/something3 to controller named 'something2' method 'something3'.

So basically, if there is only one identifier after /, then it means Home Controller, but if there are 2 identifiers it means the controller WAS specified and needs to route to that controller.

So far i have:

```
     routes.MapRoute(
              "Users",
              "Users/",
              new { controller = "Users", action = "Index" }
          );

            routes.MapRoute(
              "Projects",
             "Projects/",
               new { controller = "Projects", action = "Index" }
          );

            routes.MapRoute(
            "Tasks",
           "Tasks/",
             new { controller = "Tasks", action = "Index" }
        );

            routes.MapRoute(
               "sample",
               "{action}",
               new { controller = "Home" }
               );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

but i don't want to add a new rule for each controller that i create, i want it to be general.

Thanks,
George.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/22771625/1625737